# Proof explanation that the square root of 2 exists

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, intuition

Theorem. 
There exists $x\in\mathbb {R}: $ with ${x^2=2} $.

Can someone please share a simple proof of the above theorem by defining,

$$\{y\in\mathbb R: \mbox{$y^2\leq {2}$}\}.$$

How do we proceed to use the completeness axiom to prove the theorem? The proof that my lecturer has provided uses contradictions. He also uses the same process to define the square root function. I'm finding it difficult to grasp. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If you [edit] the question to post your lecturer's proof and flag the place that confuses you perhaps we can help.

Comment: I know, sorry. I was having difficulty writing it up so that's why I didn't.  I've posted a image of it. I'm confused from that part when delta is used and onwards. I'm not sure where the values for 'min' come from and how the quadratic terms change. Hope that helps.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but I find it funny how my answer looks like your lecturer's paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S = \{q\in\mathbb R: \mbox{$q^2<2$}\}$. Since $S \subset \Bbb R$ and $\forall x\in S(x^2<2<4)$, $2$ is upper bound for this set. Since this is a subset of real numbers, it has some real *least* upper bound $L$. If $L^2 -2 > 0,$ choose a sufficiently large $m$ such that $L' = L - 1/m$ and $L'^2 = L^2 - 2L/m + 1/m^2 > 2$, which contradicts the minimality of $L$ (try it yourself using the [Archimedian property of the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property#Archimedean_property_of_the_real_numbers)). The same for $L^2 - 2 < 0$. Thus $L^2 = 2$ and $L = \sqrt 2 \in \Bbb R$.

*Edit*: Given the original paper, my answer doesn't really help because I used the exact same process, so I'll explain the idea: completeness is pretty much what makes $\Bbb R$ without "gaps". You'll want to construct, usually, sets that look like [Dedekind cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut) which will have an upper bound (possibly the least, and that's what you'll seek) as your desired number. Since the least upper bound is always real, prove it is what you want! In the given case, the choices for $\delta$ are not arbitrary: sketch a $\delta$ that would solve your problem (small numbers that will still keep the conditions) and, if your least upper bound isn't the number you desire, you'll have a contradiction! The process of construction is like solving a one-variable  linear equation: you first *assume* there's a solution and then find what it would be, but, to formalize, you just *show* that there is a solution and then prove it's unique.